# recursive error handler

Tags: c#, reflection, recursion

I have the following code where I'm trying to get all the properties of an object as well as the property values.  Some properties can be collections or collections of collections, so I tried to set up a recursive function for those types.  Unfortunately it's not working, erroring on this line

```
if (property.GetValue(item, null) is IEnumerable)
```

and I don't know what needs changed.  Can anyone help here?  Thanks.

```
public static string PackageError(IEnumerable<object> obj)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (object o in obj)
    {
        sb.Append("<strong>Object Data - " + o.GetType().Name + "</strong>");
        sb.Append("<p>");

        PropertyInfo[] properties = o.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            if (pi.GetValue(o, null) is IEnumerable && !(pi.GetValue(o, null) is string))
                sb.Append(GetCollectionPropertyValues((IEnumerable)pi.GetValue(o, null)));
            else
                sb.Append(pi.Name + ": " + pi.GetValue(o, null) + "<br />");
        }

        sb.Append("</p>");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string GetCollectionPropertyValues(IEnumerable collectionProperty)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (object item in collectionProperty)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.GetValue(item, null) is IEnumerable)
                sb.Append(GetCollectionPropertyValues((IEnumerable)property.GetValue(item, null)));
            else
                sb.Append(property.Name + ": " + property.GetValue(item, null) + "<br />");
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: When you say erroring, is it throwing an exception? what exactly is the error?

Comment: The error message says Parameter count mismatch.

Comment: What's the source of the object?  If it's Excel, for example, it's possible that the property is an indexed property, in which case, you can't pass null to property.GetValue().

Comment: It's our own custom object, not excel or any third party object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an existing serialization mechanism, such as XML serialization or JSON serialization, to provide this information if you are trying to make it generic.

Comment: Yes, that's much easier.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that particular property is an indexer, so it's expecting you to pass index values to the GetValue method.  There is no easy way to take an indexer and determine what values are valid to pass as indices, in the general case, as a class is free to implement an indexer however it wants.  For instance, a Dictionary keyed on a string has an indexer by key, which can take indices as enumerated in the Keys property.

The typical approach to serializing collections is to handle them as a special case, treating each primitive collection type (array, List, Dictionary, etc.) individually.

Note that there is a difference here between a property returning IEnumerable and an indexer.